# C# Get Email With Attachments Older than one year

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Now I use c# with .net3.5.
I try to get mails with attachments with this piece of code:

```
private void test(Outlook.Folder folder){
        log.Info(folder.FullFolderPath);
        int i = 0;
        Outlook.Table table = folder.GetTable("@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment\"=1");
        table.Sort("[CreationTime]", false);
        while (!table.EndOfTable)
            {
                Outlook.Row row = table.GetNextRow();
                log.Info(row["CreationTime"] + " " + row["Subject"]);
                i++;
            }
        if(i>0)
          log.Info(folder.FullFolderPath + " --> " + i);
    }
```

But I got ONLY EMAILS until on 01/04/2018(one years old)... how can I get all the emails of the input folder, including those of 2017 (older than a year)??

Thanks.

Comment: Just a hint, I assume that you are using Exchange as your mail server. The default behaviour of outlook is to leave messages older than 12 months on the server. Go to your mailbox setting in outlook (File -> manage Accounts -> Your Mailbox -> Change) and change that behaviour.

Comment: I think that you are right. I can't change outlook settings. For you is it possible download others mail from Exchange Service by Outlook?

Comment: You need to look into Echange Webservices maybe there is a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution to fetch older mail from server by "OUTLOOK INTEROP library".
So only solution that I found is use "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices library", but with this solution i need to ask the credential to user :( (with OUTLOOK INTEROP library it's not necessary). I can avoid ask credential with Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, but i need of a appName and appPassword(and I can't configure the Exchange server).